# How to get specific table data from a table row using python and BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've researched everywhere and I am having trouble.....I want to access each individual element and append the values to my empty python lists...and of course after I have the correct data in my python list I am going to append them to a csv file...

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

html = urlopen("http://exoweb0.donbest.com/checkHTML/servlet/send_archive_history.servlet?by_casino=1&for_casino=37&league=1&game=0&date=20151029")
soup = BeautifulSoup((html), "html.parser")
trs = soup.findAll("tr")
dates = []
rotations = []
games = []
lines = []
types = []
for tr in trs.children:
  print(tr)
  #tds =  tr.findAll("td") 'Finds all tds in current tr
  #print (tds)
  #date = tds.contents[0] ' It reference the first element in each td
  #rot = tds[2]   ' It reference the third element in each td
  #game = tds[3] ' It reference the fourth element in each td
  #line = tds[4] ' It reference the fith element in each td
  #type_l = tds[5] ' It reference the sixth element in each td

  #dates.append(date)  Trying to append to my empty list
  #rotations.append(rot)
  #games.append(game)
  #lines.append(line)
  #types.append(type_l)
```

Comment: The link does not work for me. Getting 404.

Comment: http://exoweb0.donbest.com/checkHTML/servlet/send_archive_history.servlet?by_casino=1&for_casino=37&league=1&game=0&date=20151029 try this one..   :-)

Comment: That URL requires a login. I suppose a valid question is: Are you accounting for this login page before you attempt to scrape the page?

Comment: Hey andy I am scrapping this for a friend when I put down the link it just auto goes in without a username or password and it displays the info I need..so I don't have the login... :-(

Comment: Hey I finally scraped everything I needed using pandas function read html...